# Can't submit values to database after changing html attributes

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to make a password changing option in one of my works.

WHAT I WANT TO DO IS:
1. First verify the current password. 
2. If the current password entered is correct then the 'proceed' button shifts down and a new field called 'confirm' is displayed.
3. When it is displayed, the attribute of the fields and button is changed.
4. Then I want to enter the new password and confirm password in the respective fileds and check whether both fields have same value.
5. If both have same value then a table is updated and if not an alert is made.

PROBLEM:
From Step 4, i am facing the problem. Whenever I give wrong values in both the fields, I get the error as 'Incorrect Password' and not as 'Password and Confirm Password does not match!'.

Where I am possibly going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#Button1').click(function()
    {
        var password=$('#password').val();
        var dataString = 'password='+password;
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data: dataString,
            url: "activateSettings.php",
            cache:false,
            success: function(html){
                if(html){
                    alert('Incorrect Password');
                }
                else{
                    $('#password').attr('id', 'newpassword');
                    $('#newpassword').attr('name', 'newpassword');
                    $('#newpassword').val('');
                    $('#newpassword').attr('placeholder', 'Enter your new password');

                    $('#confirm').css("visibility", "visible");

                    $('#Button1').addClass('move');
                    $('#Button1').val('Change');
                    $('#Button1').attr('id', 'ButtonChange');
                    $('#ButtonChange').attr('name', 'ButtonChange');
                }
            }
        });
    });


    $('#ButtonChange').click(function()
    {
        var newpassword=$('#newpassword').val();
        var confirmpassword = $('#confirm').val();

        var dataString = 'newpassword='+newpassword+'&confirmpassword='+confirmpassword;

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data: dataString,
            url: "activateSettings.php",
            cache:false,
            success: function(html){
                if(html){
                    alert('Password and Confirm Password does not match!');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['password']))
{
    $found = false;
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $user = $_SESSION['username'];
    $sql = "SELECT salt, password, firstname, lastname FROM user WHERE username = '$user'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    if ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $salt = $data['salt'];
        $crypt_pass = hash('sha256', $salt.$password);
            if ($crypt_pass == $data['password'])
            {
                    $found = true;
        }
    }
        mysqli_close($db);

        if($found == false)
        {
        echo '0';
    }
}
else
if(isset($_POST['newpassword']) && isset($_POST['confirmpassword']))
{
    $newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];
        $confirmpass = $_POST['confirmpassword'];

    if($newpassword == $confirmpass)
    {
        //Create SALT
        $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(6, $cstrong);
            $salt   = bin2hex($bytes);
        //Encrypt PASSWORD with SALT
        $crypt_pass = hash('sha256', $salt.$password);

        $sql = "UPDATE `user` SET `salt` = $salt, `password` = $crypt_pass WHERE `username` = '$user'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
            mysqli_close($db);
    }
    else{
        echo '0';
    }
}
?>
```

HTML

```
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter your current password">
        <input type="password" id="confirm" name="confirm" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Re-type password">
        <input type="submit" id="Button1" name="proceed" value="Proceed">
```

Update: I tried the script given by Naresh. It shows me the proper messages but no effect to database is made.

Comment: [Don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)  and [use the proper methods to hash passwords with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html).

Comment: Have you checked if the current password is valid? it would be easier if you join all the fields together `current password, new password, confirm new password` then submit button

Comment: Yes the current password is valid. What do you mean by joining the fields? I didnt get you.

Comment: Do you mean to display the 3 fielda together and do all the checking in one go??

Comment: @Ayan yes -- let me know if u need an example

Comment: Surely..I would like help from everyone.

Answer (score -1):

**Change your script**

```
<script>
function check(val)
{
  var type=$(val).attr("name");
    if(type=="proceed")
    {
        var password=$('#password').val();
        var dataString = 'password='+password;
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data: dataString,
            url: "test.php",
            cache:false,
            success: function(html){
                if(html=="false"){
                    alert('Incorrect Password');
                }
                else{ 
                    $('#password').attr('id', 'newpassword');
                    $('#newpassword').attr('name', 'newpassword');
                    $('#newpassword').val('');
                    $('#newpassword').attr('placeholder', 'Enter your new password');

                    $('#confirm').css("visibility", "visible");

                    $('#Button1').addClass('move');
                    $('#Button1').val('Change');
                    $('#Button1').attr('id', 'ButtonChange');
                    $('#ButtonChange').attr('name', 'ButtonChange');
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else if(type=="ButtonChange")
    {
        var newpassword=$('#newpassword').val();
        var confirmpassword = $('#confirm').val();

        var dataString = 'newpassword='+newpassword+'&confirmpassword='+confirmpassword;

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data: dataString,
            url: "test.php",
            cache:false,
            success: function(html){
                 if(html=="false"){
                    alert('Password and Confirm Password does not match!');
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

**Change your button to**

```
<input type="submit" id="Button1" name="proceed" value="Proceed" onclick="check(this)">
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
//include 'connect.php';
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['password']))
{
    $found = false;
    $password = $_POST['password'];
//    $user = $_SESSION['username'];


    if( $password=="test")
    {
        echo "true";
    }
    else
        echo "false";
}
else
if(isset($_POST['newpassword']) && isset($_POST['confirmpassword']))
{
    $newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];
        $confirmpass = $_POST['confirmpassword'];

    if($newpassword == $confirmpass)
    {
        echo "true";
    }
    else{
       echo "false";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Ok I am giving it a try. Along with it is my php code correct?

Comment: I think so , only do echo "false" instead of echo "0"  because we are checking that value in if condition  of Jquery.

Comment: In both places of 0? The whole script should be placed outside of document ready?? I dont know why it is saying incorrect password inspite of giving the correct password.

Comment: yes in both places of 0 and copy paste script  as it is (not need document ready as we are calling that function on onclick event )

Comment: Ok I did as you said but it is always  showing me incorrect password.  Would you mind looking in the (!html) part??

Comment: I have edited some code of script and added php code. so now copy everything as it is and you will get results. only you have to change php code for database query's

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79154/discussion-between-naresh-and-ayan).

Comment: Ok..now the error msgs pops up correctly but no changes to database occurs.